# Popup virtual keyboard that allows international characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I'm looking for a specific Javascript solution for an application we're working on.  We actually used to have it, but we've lost it (facepalm).  What happened was the following:

1. Click keyboard image
2. Virtual keyboard popped up allowing user to choose a bunch of international keys (such as umlauts for Germany, Cyrillic for Serbian, etc.)

I've done various searches on Google for "Javascript popup keyboard", "Javascript international keys keyboard", "Virtual javascript keyboard", etc. but have found no results.  Then, I remembered MooTools and the amazing job they do and found a virtual keyboard that does something similar, but not exactly what we want.

http://mootools.net/forge/p/accentedkeyboard

Unfortunately, it only displays once the character 'a' is typed (and displays all variations with umlauts, strikes above, etc.)  What we need is that virtual keyboard that displays once an image is clicked and shows ALL international characters.

Comment: See http://mottie.github.com/Keyboard/

Comment: Thank you very much, bfavaretto!  That's pretty close to what I'm looking for as is the following like, [link](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard), but the one I linked to in this comment is VERY similar to the one we used before, but not exact.  I'm looking for those "tiny" keyboards.

Comment: *All* international characters? All 110,000 of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has on screen keyboard:
https://www.google.com/inputtools/try/

Comment: This site is a little misleading: the plugin does not use jQuery at all.

Comment: :-) I've assumed from title that it depends on jQuery

Comment: The site posted currently is listed as potentially dangerous by Google (see http://safebrowsing.clients.google.com/safebrowsing/diagnostic?site=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ajaxblender.com%2Fjquery-virtual-keyboard.html). You may want to look on the project homepage which is found here: http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard

Comment: Thanks Martin. Replaced link with Google screen keyboard. It is also quite nice.