# set languge arabic for input and another in french in same form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, windows, jsp

I turn JavaScript forum in espoire to find a solution to my problem because right now I do not know or seek "in php or JavaScript" good my problem is in a form that I veus create the user must enter the information of use in two different languages "Arabic and French" .and I wondered if y'avais a moyer for the language chagement be automatic. "Arabic language = in the book field has seized the Arab" and when I position myself in another field or seized must be in French language changes automatically to the French
I hope qulqu'un poura answer me.

Comment: Actually you want the keyboard input language to change automatically, the unicode characters generated by keys. It is not possible to do this automatically in javascript. See also [change keyboard input language for some fields with javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095432/change-keyboard-input-language-for-some-fields-with-javascript) for additional comments and links to follow.

Comment: Have you considered offering a french/arabic virtual keyboard, [http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/javascript/keyboard) for example. I have not used it myself, but it came up in [Popup virtual keyboard that allows international characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040039/popup-virtual-keyboard-that-allows-international-characters)

Answer (score 1):

Use `lang` attribute:

```
<input lang="fr">
<input lang="ar">
```

Comment: i use spring mvc : <f:input type="text" path="nomArabe"  lang="ar"  /> this not work

Comment: is possible to switch languague system by javascript to select arabic